# Applying default value with || without re-assigning a variable in JS

Tags: javascript

What I need is to set default values using "||" operator

```
let minValue = parseInt(prompt('Minimal value','0'));
let maxValue = parseInt(prompt('Maximum value','100'));

minValue = !isNaN() || 0;
maxValue = !isNaN() || 100;
```

My idea is if I put NaN, it returns false and assigns default values. However, if I put any other numbers in prompt, it still assigns 0 and 100, any ways to get around it? I need it to be done with "||"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new logical assignment operator instead, which extends off of `||`.

```
minValue ||= 0;
maxValue ||= 100;
```

Or alternate after the `parseInt` call.

```
const minValue = parseInt(prompt('Minimal value','0')) || 0;
const maxValue = parseInt(prompt('Maximum value','100')) || 100;
```

This

```
minValue = !isNaN() || 0;
```

does not make sense because you need to pass something into `isNaN` for it to return a sensible value.